# Ansible playbook erring out

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I'm trying to execute cert-util provided by elastic on a remote host but, it's complaining about the structure of the playbook but, I have a similar playbook that works fine and I am not seeing the difference. I feel like I need a second set of eyes.

I have tried various changes to the top of the playbook like adding

- name: Setup certs

but, it complains about - name. I'm coming from a salt background and new to ansible so, I feel like im missing some type of structuring of it.

```
  hosts: elasticnodes
  become: true

  vars:
    elasticsearch_path_home: "/usr/share/elasticsearch"
    elasticsearch_path_etc: "/etc/elasticsearch"
    elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass: "plop99"
    elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass: "plop99"
    elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir: "certs"
    elasticsearch_user: "elasticsearch"
    elasticsearch_user_group: "elasticsearch"

  tasks:

    - name: Create a certificate directory
      file:
        owner: root
        group: '{{ elasticsearch_user_group }}'
        mode: u=rwx,g+rx,o-rwx
        path: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'
        state: directory
      when: elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir is defined

    - name: Check a certificate of authority
      stat:
        path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-stack-ca.p12"
        register: elastic_stack_ca_file

    - name: Generate a certificate of authority
      args:
        chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
        become: yes
        command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}'"
      when: not elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists

    - name: Check a certificate and private key for a node
      stat:
        path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-certificates.p12"
        register: elastic_certificates_file

    - name: Generate a certificate and private key for a node
      args:
        chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
        become: yes
        command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}' --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-certificates.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass }}'"
      when: elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists and not elastic_certificates_file.stat.exists
```

This gives an error of

```
ERROR! A playbook must be a list of plays, got a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'> instead

The error appears to be in '/root/elastic/ansible/playbooks/cert_setup.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  hosts: elasticnodes
  ^ here
```

yet a playbook like this works fine.

```
# modify the /etc/sysctl.conf file
- name: Configure sysctl.conf and /etc/hosts
  hosts: elasticnodes
  become: true

  vars:
    fqdn: "domain.com"

  tasks:
    - name: Configure sysctl
      sysctl:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
        state: present
        reload: yes
        sysctl_set: yes
      with_items:
         - { name: vm.swappiness, value: 1 }

# modify the /etc/hosts file work in progress
    - name: Build hosts file
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/hosts
        regexp: '.*{{ item }}$'
        line: '{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{item}}.{{fqdn}} {{item}}'
        state: present
      with_items: '{{ groups["etc_hosts"] }}'

    - name: Update Host Names
      hostname:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

# start firewall
    - name: Enable firewalld
      service:
        name: firewalld
        state: started
        enabled: yes

# restart firewall
    - name: Restart firewalld
      service:
        name: firewalld
        state: restarted
        enabled: yes

# Update firewall rules
    - name: Update Firewall Settings
      ansible.posix.firewalld:
        zone: public
        permanent: yes
        immediate: yes
        state: enabled
        port: 9200/tcp

# Update firewall rules
    - name: Update Firewall Settings
      ansible.posix.firewalld:
        zone: public
        permanent: yes
        immediate: yes
        state: enabled
        port: 9300/tcp
```

I'm not totally sure what I am missing and feel like its pretty obvious.

Comment: Need a - before hosts, this is a yaml file.  Needs to be formatted correctly

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You should also read through the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) to learn the basic concepts and syntax. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting.

Answer (score 1):

The error is `A playbook must be a list of plays`. The first playbook is missing `-` at the beginning then you don't have a list plays, and the tasks with `args` don't have the module `command`. Try as below.

```
   -  hosts: elasticnodes
      become: true
    
      vars:
        elasticsearch_path_home: "/usr/share/elasticsearch"
        elasticsearch_path_etc: "/etc/elasticsearch"
        elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass: "plop99"
        elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass: "plop99"
        elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir: "certs"
        elasticsearch_user: "elasticsearch"
        elasticsearch_user_group: "elasticsearch"
    
      tasks:
    
        - name: Create a certificate directory
          file:
            owner: root
            group: '{{ elasticsearch_user_group }}'
            mode: u=rwx,g+rx,o-rwx
            path: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'
            state: directory
          when: elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir is defined
    
        - name: Check a certificate of authority
          stat:
            path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-stack-ca.p12"
            register: elastic_stack_ca_file
    
        - name: Generate a certificate of authority
          command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}'"
          args:
            chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
            become: yes
          when: not elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists
    
        - name: Check a certificate and private key for a node
          stat:
            path: "{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}/elastic-certificates.p12"
            register: elastic_certificates_file
    
        - name: Generate a certificate and private key for a node
          command: "'{{ elasticsearch_path_home }}'/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-stack-ca.p12 --ca-pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_pass }}' --out '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}/{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_dir }}'/elastic-certificates.p12 --pass '{{ elasticsearch_tls_cert_ca_pass }}'"
          args:
            chdir: '{{ elasticsearch_path_etc }}'
            become: yes
          when: elastic_stack_ca_file.stat.exists and not elastic_certificates_file.stat.exists
```

It's one best practices name your plays as your second playbook, I recommend you read the best practices to improve your playbooks.

https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials

Check the official documentation of `command` module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html

Comment: I edited my post to reflect that. I actually tried that before I made this post and quite a few others just changing and rerunning. Feels like im spinning in circles that's why I made the post.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I used `--syntax-check` with your playbook and I noted that you were using `command` like as an argument instead of using it as a module. I edited my answer with that correction. I hope It can help you, if you have other error I'll help you gladly.